# Using sub() to replace entire field in R

Tags: regex, r

I want to use the sub() function to replace a field in my R data frame. (If I should be using a different function to do this please let me know.)

The issue I'm running into is that the sub() function replaces only the matching regex, which makes total sense. But how do I alter my sub() function to replace the entire field?

Here is the repro:

```
Brow = c("Mozilla/5.0 xxxx", "Mozilla Firefox")
ver = c("1", "2")
test3 = data.frame(Brow, ver)
test3
#                Brow   ver
# 1  Mozilla/5.0 xxxx    1
# 2  Mozilla Firefox     2
## this is my sub() function
test3$Brow = sub("Mozilla\\/5\\.0", "Internet Explorer", test3$Brow)
# output
test3
#                     Brow   ver
# 1  Internet Explorer xxxx   1
# 2         Mozilla Firefox   2
```

The output I would like:

```
               Brow  ver
1  Internet Explorer  1
2  Mozilla Firefox    2
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `grepl` to find which ones match and then use that as the index for a replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sub('Mozilla(?=[/][0-9]).*', 'Internet Explorer', test3$Brow, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "Internet Explorer" "Mozilla Firefox"
```

Or just

```
sub('Mozilla[/][0-9].*', 'Internet Explorer', test3$Brow)
#[1] "Internet Explorer" "Mozilla Firefox"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was just waiting for the allotted time to pass. Thanks again.